# Insert a dictionary in all data of a Django QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am getting the Django Query Set output like this.

```
<QuerySet 
  [
    {
     'transaction_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 28, 13, 39, 47, 66880, tzinfo=<UTC>), 
     'coin': 200
    },{
      'transaction_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 28, 13, 39, 54, 132439, tzinfo=<UTC>), 
      'coin': 150
    }]>
```

I want to insert a key value pair in all quesryset inside the list. The desired output should be.

```
    <QuerySet [
    {
      'transaction_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 28, 13, 39, 47, 66880, tzinfo=<UTC>),      
       'coin': 200, 
       'transiction_type':'credit'
    }, {
       'transaction_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 28, 13, 39, 54, 132439, tzinfo=<UTC>),    
       'coin': 150, 
       'transiction_type':'credit'
     } ]>
```

I have done this By this way.

```
    coin_withdraw_list =[dict(coin_withdraw,transaction_type="CREDIT") for coin_withdraw in user_withdraw_list]
```

But I am looking for if there any way to do this using any Django function. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add an additional field with a string literal to all entries in the QuerySet you can use [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) with a [`Value`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions) expression:

```py
from django.db.models import CharField, Value

...

queryset.annotate(transaction_type=Value('credit', output_field=CharField()))
```

Comment: not Working.. showing me this error..  django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my answer - it should fix the issue.